# Problemas al seleccionar en una tabla

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Tengo este formulario]

Quiero que al presionar el botón seleccionar, el que está de color verde, los datos se reflejen en los campos que aparecen ahí, por alguna razón cuando hago esta acción, solo se selecciona los campos de textos pero no los combobox, este es mi código:

```
protected void idTablauser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int fila = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("idseleccionaruser"))
        {
            iduser_original.Text = idTablauser.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Text;
            tnombre_rol.Text = idTablauser.Rows[fila].Cells[1].Text;
            tnombreusuario.Text = idTablauser.Rows[fila].Cells[2].Text;                  
            dprivilegio.SelectedValue = idTablauser.Rows[fila].Cells[4].Text;
            destado.SelectedValue = idTablauser.Rows[fila].Cells[5].Text;
            tclave_user.Enabled = false;
            idEditaruser.Enabled = true;
            idAgregaruser.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: no deberias pasarle el index del combo?

Comment: Debería ser el INDEX como bien dice Ramiro